# Why is my regex coming back false when I test it on my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

First time trying to write a regex
I'm trying to create a format that matches 1234567-89-0234.
The regex I have created is;
/^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$/
However it keeps coming back false, perhaps it's an error in my script as well

```
    function showAnamneseFisico()


{
      function nullCheck() { 
var y = /^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$/; 
var x = $("#nidNumber");
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
if (x[i].test(y) === false){
  return 0;
}
 }

    if (nullCheck() === 0) {
      alert ('Você ainda não tenham completado o preenchimento da tabela de Numeros NID. Faz favor, verifique que você respondeu a cada pergunta e submeter mais uma vez.');
}
  else if ($("#formNotCompleteResponse").val() === ''){
    alert ('Você ainda não tenham completado o preenchimento porque você não prover um razão que nao fez todo deste formulário. Faz favor, prover uma resposta a esse pergunta e submeter mais uma vez.');
  }
  else {    
    $("#anamneseFisico").show();
    $("#buttonExame").show();
    $("#buttonNid").hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the loop for `x`. `$("#nidNumber")` will only return one element. Also, what is an example of the input's value that you are testing?

Comment: Also, you can simplify your regex: \d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}

Comment: This regex appears to work for me `^[0-9]{7}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}$`. Looks a little nicer.

Comment: Jinx @nevermind! Yours is even nicer.

Comment: @price, Thanks I caught the # error shortly after posting, replacing it with a . to signify class which will return an array. (Error in a copy paste from earlier attempts at writing this.)  And then I replaced my reg ex. with the one suggested by nevermind  (\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}) but had to change it to var y =  /^\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}/; so it wouldn't throw errors but then the whole thing stopped working.  Complete code can be found here if interested, http://jsbin.com/tuvezolanu/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the correct ways are:

```
/\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}/.test("string"); //returns a boolean - would match the pattern in a string.
```

If you want a strict match, such as pattern only, then:

```
/^\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test("string");
```

Or

```
"string".match(/\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}/); //returns an array of matches or null
"string".match(/^\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/); //pattern only match
```

So, your code becomes:

```
function nullCheck() { 
    var y = /\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}/; // or /^\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/
    var x = $("#nidNumber");
    return y.test(x.val()); // returns true or false
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh you are a genius!  Works perfectly now, I must have confused which places the string and the regex were supposed to go in when adapting from the examples I had found searching the web

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the escaping of `-` which is only a special char when within `[]`.

On a side note, the wrapping brackets are unnecessary.

Here is a shorter version: `^\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4}$`